# google maps markers is not being removed after adding new

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm currently working on an app which shows the bus location to students !
The problem is when i remove a marker with `marker.remove();` or `map.clear();` from the map and retrieve a new location and show it on the map, the old one is still shown.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
  public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Webi.with(getContext())
          .from("http://31.25.91.60:8888/GetResult.php")
          .onResponse(new OnResponse() {
            @Override
            public void Response(String content, String s1) {
              try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(content);
                if(arr.length() > 0) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    name.add(jobj.getString("driverid"));
                    lat.add(jobj.getString("lat"));
                    latlong.add(jobj.getString("longlat"));
                    time.add(jobj.getString("time"));
                  }

                  for(int index = 0; index < name.size(); index++) {
                    final int finalIndex = index;
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        try {
                          LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat.get(finalIndex)),Double.parseDouble(latlong.get(finalIndex)));
                          MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(point)
                            .title(name.get(finalIndex))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_pin));
                          marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                          markers.add(marker);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "چیزی پیدا نشد !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  map.clear();
                }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                map.clear();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }).connect();
      }
    }, 0, 10000);
    LatLng university = new LatLng(36.2497511,58.8287331);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
      .target(university)
      .zoom(17)
      .bearing(90)
      .tilt(40)
      .build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        for(int index = 0; index < markers.size(); index++) {
          marker = markers.get(index);
          marker.remove();
          map.clear();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      handler.postDelayed(this, 9000);
    }
  };
```

Every 10 second date fetches from server and every 9 second markers must get deleted

Comment: try `markers.clear();`& `map.clear()` before `map.animateCamera`

Comment: @Eminem Did not make any difference

Comment: before this line `marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);` call `map.clear();`

Comment: @Eminem the code you are talking about is inside a for loop and if i have multi markers then it will show just one

Comment: so does it works?

Comment: @Eminem I'am not sure but i think marker is deleted because no other markers are shown

Comment: please give a proper response,try it and let me know.If that works we will find another way to do it

Comment: @Eminem I try your code it removes the markers from map ! but when i add this line `map.clear();` before for loop it don't works !

Comment: when you say before loop, where do mean?

Comment: @Eminem before `for(int index = 0; index < name.size(); index++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `map.clear()` and the whole `for` loop into the UI thread Runnable.  I think that you will always want to clear the map just before adding new markers.  Otherwise, you will have issues syncing the two operations.  For example, after 2 runs the markers would be removed at 18 seconds and then not added until 20 seconds.

Also, I don't see where you are ever clearing your data lists, are you doing this before adding the new response data?

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        map.clear();
        for(int index = 0; index < name.size(); index++) {
            try {
                LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat.get(index)), Double.parseDouble(latlong.get(index)));
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(point)
                        .title(name.get(index))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus_pin));
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                markers.add(marker);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code before but got no answer(My code is inside `onMapReady() => Timer => TimerTask` which always run task every 10 second , i think maybe the problem with these methods)

Comment: Are you ever clearing your response data before adding the new responses?

Comment: Are refer to this code: `markers.add(marker)`?  no i don't clear this list because i used it to determine the total markers but when use map.clear() normally it should clear all map but it doesn't do that

Comment: No I mean the name, lat,latlong, etc lists.  If you are only adding the new data and not removing the old, you will re-add the old markers in the for loop also.

Comment: Oh my god !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i was coding hard for this all the time for a week but this is very strange for me and i think that this is google map problem but ...... Thanks bro , you are true lifesaver :D